# How to pass input through a switch statement in another class

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm new to coding and have a question regarding using switch statements from other classes. This is my original functional class which takes user input and then gives information about the pricing of a condo. First the user is asked to choose a condo type (#1-3), then they are prompted to decide whether they want a parking spot or a garage (1 or 2). I am trying to split the class apart so that only the methods are in one class and the rest of the code in the main method is in another (test class). The problem I've been running into is figuring out a way to pass user input through the switch statement. I've tried to look up ways to do so, but haven't had any luck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CondoSales

{  

public static void main(String[] args)   

{


System.out.println("Please select one of the following for pricing 
information: " +
"1 for a condo with a park view, 2 for a condo with a golf course view, or 3 
for a condo with a lake view.");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int priceSelection;
priceSelection = input.nextInt();

final int PARK_VIEW = 150000;
final int GOLF_COURSE_VIEW = 175000;
final int LAKE_VIEW = 210000;
int parkingCost;

  switch(priceSelection)

  {

     case (1): 
        System.out.println("The condo with a park view costs $" + PARK_VIEW);
        parkingCost = PARK_VIEW;
     break;

     case (2): 
        System.out.println("The condo with a golf course view costs $" + GOLF_COURSE_VIEW);
        parkingCost = GOLF_COURSE_VIEW;
     break;

     case (3):
        System.out.println("The condo with a lake view costs $" + LAKE_VIEW + ".");
        parkingCost = LAKE_VIEW;
     break;

     default:
        System.out.println("$0");
        parkingCost = 0;

  }         

 System.out.println("Select 1 for a parking spot or 2 for a garage:");   

  int parkingSpecification;
  parkingSpecification = input.nextInt();   

  switch(parkingSpecification)

  {

     case (1):
        System.out.println("With a parking spot, the cost is $" + parkingCost);
     break;

     case (2):
        System.out.println("With a garage, the cost is $" + (parkingCost + 5000));  
     break;

     default:
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response; the condo will cost $" + parkingCost + ".");   
 }
 }
 }
```

Here is the test class which I have yet to figure out how to pass the price selection input through to the switch from the original class. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been hitting my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCondoSales

{

final int PARK_VIEW = 150000;
final int GOLF_COURSE_VIEW = 175000;
final int LAKE_VIEW = 210000;
int parkingCost;

public static void main(String[] args)   

{

CondoSales methodRetrieval = new CondoSales();


System.out.println("Please select one of the following for pricing 
information: " +
"1 for a condo with a park view, 2 for a condo with a golf course view, or 3 
for a condo with a lake view.");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int priceSelection;
priceSelection = input.nextInt();


methodRetrieval.priceReturn(priceSelection);


System.out.println("Select 1 for a parking spot or 2 for a garage:"); 

int parkingSpecification;
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
parkingSpecification = input.nextInt();  

methodRetrieval.parkingReturn(parkingSpecification);




}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only the methods are in one class"?  Both your methods are called `main` - you haven't written any others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the switch criteria as a method parameter in another class, and then passing the input to that method.  For instance:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CondoPriceSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriceSelector selector = new PriceSelector();
        try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
            int priceSelection = scan.nextInt();
            selector.printPrice(priceSelection);
        }
    }
}

class PriceSelector {
    final int parkingCost = 5000;

    public void printPrice(int selection) {
        switch (selection) {
            case (1):
                System.out.println("With a parking spot, the cost is $" + parkingCost);
                break;
            case (2):
                System.out.println("With a garage, the cost is $" + (parkingCost + 5000));  
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response; the condo will cost $" + parkingCost + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it!